# How to detect mining based on power consumption?

Tags: mining

Is there any data from power consumption of ASICs to understand the mining process? Is there any pattern to know about that?

Comment: Give some more explanation to your question. What do you exactly want to know?

Comment: I want to detect a person does mining or not ? the only information which is available is the power consumption of that customer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any data from power consumption of ASICs to understand the
>   mining process? Is there any pattern to know about that?

**AFAIK, ASIC miners in general doesn't have any feature where they can report the power usage.**

Detecting mining activity on your computer or through your browser can typically be spotted by observing the CPU usage from within your OS resource manager. A spike when visiting certain sites (sites that should not be taxing your CPU) could indicate active cryptojacking activity through JS. 
 
 If your goal is to detect cryptojacking malware, you could check for behavioural patterns which varies a lot among the myriad of cryptojacking malware out there (a change in behavioural pattern makes it harder to detect by AV programs).

Comment: My question is about exactly about ASIC miners power consumption report. Is there any data about that?

Comment: have look at this article: https://www.kompulsa.com/bitcoin-miner-power-consumption-much-energy-bitcoin-miners-consume/